# Most efficient way to column values to create a tables in access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table with recipes. For each recipes ID I have 5 columns (ingredient1,ingredient2 etc) were I store the names of ingredients. Then in the same table I have 5 columns were I have the corresponding amount of each ingredient (amount1 for ingredient1 etc).

The way the table was build and the data entered, and item like "eggs" can be stored in the ingredient1 column for recipe 1  and in the ingredient5 column for recipe 2.

What I would like to do is create a table were the header of the columns becomes the name of the different ingredients in the table and then store the amount of each ingredient in the right column.

I see how I can go that by using the following steps:

1. go through all the ingredients of the original table and create a column for each ingredient.
2. go back in the table, and for each recipes read each ingredient, find the corresponding amount, find the corresponding column in the new table using the name of the ingredient and add the amount in the new table.

It seems to me that doing this could become a slow process if I have to go through over 500 recipes. But is that the only way to do it or is there a more automated ways to do this. Almost like automatically creating a matrix.

Comment: Yes, there is a better way - perform a database normalization. Instead of having columns for each ingredient, create a detail table below Recipe called RecipeIngredient. This table will have composite Primary Key consisting of the Foreign Key field ReferenceId and a SequenceNo field (which orders the ingredients).

Comment: This mean I need to change the whole structure of the database when I import the files ? Indeed I forgot to mention is that the data are imported from excel in the first way, and have to be exported to a text or excel file in the second way to be analyzed with a third party software (Spotfire). During exporting I also include additional data. I used the example of recipes because it was easier for me to explain but I'm actually dealing with chemical product formula mixtures.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should use `ListObjects` in VBA for easy access to data in excel tables.

You can wrap a range of cells with a ListObject by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or, in VBA, by calling `ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(%range%)` method.